# Python Find specific url from website

Tags: python, request, web-crawler

In some reason, I need to find every url which contains `menu` in a specific website.

Like this http://www.ipeen.com.tw/shop/607566/menu

The problem is that, not every restaurants contain `menus`, if I try to send `requests.get` to http://www.ipeen.com.tw/shop/10000, it will threw

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.ipeen.com.tw', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)
```

So, I thought I need to find every restaurants first, and then send requests to `shop/xxxxxx/menu` to find out it has menu or not.

Is there a better way to find out?  I've tried advance google search like
[site:www.ipeen.com.tw/shop inurl:menu](http://site:www.ipeen.com.tw/shop%20inurl:menu), but it's harder to crawl the result of google search, it probably would block me.

Comment: `Restaurant`s, which aren't shops, contain `menu`s.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that.